# Node name from an xml file using lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I have an xml file with a structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<root>

<Validity>
  <OneValidity a=1>----</OneValidity>
  <OneValidity a=2>----</OneValidity>
</Validity>

<ValidityLine>
  <OneValidityLinea a=1>----</OneValidityLine>
  <OneValidityLinea a=2>----</OneValidityLine>      
</ValidityLine>

</root>
```

I'd like to return, using python and lxml library, the parents node name: `Validity` and `ValidityLine`.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: It seems it's always complaining if any of the node names starts with a number , like `1a` and `2`

Comment: That's not a valid XML document. Names cannot start with a digit.

Comment: just edit my question, sorry it wasnt clear. I hope now it's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
validityLst = root.xpath('Validity')
validityLineLst = root.xpath('ValidityLine')
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already used this code and it works. But Can i return the parents node name, without specify in the code the parents node name ('Validity' and 'ValidityLine'). Is' it possible work on the strcuture of the xml file and his hierarchy?

Comment: @user2418290: Sure. You can use `root.getchildren()` to retrieve the children of the `root` elem: `Validity` and `ValidityLinea`.

Comment: perfect it works using: `tree = etree.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    children = root.getchildren()
    print children[0].tag
    print children[1].tag `

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer years later and wanted to provide a more concise answer to what I believe OP was asking (and the question that brought me here from Google):

```
from lxml import etree

# Parse file and get root node
tree = etree.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# Access root node name
name = root.tag
```

Note: the `tag` attribute provides the name of the current node.